# Munchkin: Charity: Giving cards to someone who has 5 already

Tags: munchkin

In the charity phase of munchkin when you have to reduce your hand to 5 cards.

A rule states:

> Charity: If you have more than five cards in your hand, you must play
>   enough cards to get you to five or below. If you cannot, or do not
>   want to, you must give the excess cards to the player with the lowest
>   Level.

Q: what if the player with the lowest level already has 5 cards?

Do you?

- Still give them to the player
- Discard them

Answer (score 26, accepted):

You still give them. But those players must discard extra cards at their charity phase (if they are still the player with the lowest level).

This rule gives a slight advantage to players with the lowest level. Although they mostly get the less usefull cards (gee two halfling and a thief card, I'm really happy now!)

To add some reference to the [rules](http://www.worldofmunchkin.com/rules/munchkin_rules.pdf):

The answer is in the rules (the relevant part in bold):

> Your Hand: Cards in your hand are not in play. They don’t help you, but
>   they can’t be taken away except by cards that specifically affect “your hand.”
>   **At the end of your turn, you may have no more than five cards in your hand
>   (see Charity, p. 2)**.

It clearly states, that the hand limit is checked at the end of your turn. So it is no problem if you have 25 cards because of the charity of several players. At the end of your turn you need to level it to 5 (or 6 if you are a dwarf).

And charity is defined as:

> (3) Charity: If you have more than five cards in your hand, you must play
>   enough cards to get you to five or below. **If you cannot, or do not want to, you must give the excess cards to the player with the lowest Level**. If players are tied for lowest, divide the cards as evenly as possible, but it’s up to you who gets the bigger set(s) of leftovers. If YOU are the lowest or tied for lowest, just discard the excess.

Comment: While I have not seen this written any were I find it to be a fair and satisfactory answer.

Comment: I have added the relevant parts of the rules.

Answer (score 22):

*You still give them to the player.*

While you've already got a correct answer, I'd like to explain it a bit further. Specifically, *there is no hand limit.* The *only* rule that deals with having too many cards in your hand is the charity rule, which describes what you do during your own charity phase. It doesn't place a limit on players' hands in general, it just describes a condition (when you get to the charity phase of your turn *and* you have more than five cards *and* you do not play them all) and an action (give the cards to a particular player). So there's no conflict here. There's nothing stopping you from giving them the cards, and there's nothing causing them to discard the cards. You just do what the rule says, and nothing more.